# Google Sheets Apps Script. Function to check if number is Prime

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have been looking for a Google Sheets Apps Script function that can be entered in cell B1 to check if cell A1 contains a prime number or not. So far I can't find anything.

I have the VBA code for Excel but would like to port my spread sheet to Google Sheets.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just take the code on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test and translate it to apps script - adding a few extra checks to see if n is really a valid number.

```
function isprime(n) {
  if(typeof n !== "number") return false;
  if(Math.floor(n) !== n) return false;
  if(n <= 1) return false;
  if(n <= 3) return true;
  if(n % 2 === 0 || n % 3 === 0) return false;
  for(var i = 5; i*i <= n; i += 6) {
    if(n % i === 0  || n % (i + 2) === 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```